# How to automatically align similar lines of code using whitespace in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Is there an existing macro or plugin which will turn this

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
public Person Mother { get; set; }
```

into this?

```
public string Name   { get; set; }
public int    Age    { get; set; }
public Person Mother { get; set; }
```

I'll have a go at describing the algorithm which I *think* is intuitively obvious - (for a particular selection) make each token on a line as left as possible, but not more left than any token of the same index on any of the other lines.

Comment: Why? You should always use the teams chosen editor as it works, otherwise when the next guy works on it it will turn out really horrible. The original reads fine, code is a story, not a spreadsheet. Bets too get used to it

Comment: As already mentioned it is not a good code style to align your code (bad readability). One reason is that your code may look horrible on other systems if using tabs for alignment. This is because tabs are defined by the system. If your are using four whitespaces as tab, someone else may use 3 whitespaces for tabs. Therefore ensure you turn on the Visual Studio Editor option to convert tabs into whitespaces.

Answer (score 12):

Here is a primitive "Align Properties" macro to demonstrate how to accomplish this type of functionality using Visual Studio macros.

```vb
Sub AlignProperties()
    Dim win As EnvDTE.Window = DTE.ActiveWindow
    If win.Type <> EnvDTE.vsWindowType.vsWindowTypeDocument Then
        MsgBox("This macro can only be run in an active text editor window.")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Determine the affected lines.
    Dim startLine As Integer = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.TopLine
    Dim endLine As Integer = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.BottomLine
    If endLine < startLine Then
        Dim temp As Integer = startLine
        startLine = endLine
        endLine = temp
    End If
    endLine = endLine - 1

    ' Parse the four columns: modifier, type, identifier, and rest.
    Dim regex = New Regex("(\s+)(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)\s+({.*)")
    Dim leading As String = Nothing
    Dim array(endLine - startLine, 3) As String
    Dim widths(3) As Integer
    For i As Integer = 0 To endLine - startLine
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.GotoLine(startLine + i)
        DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
        Dim line As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.text()
        Dim match As Match = regex.Match(line)
        If leading = Nothing Then
            leading = match.Groups(1).ToString()
        End If
        For j As Integer = 0 To 3
            Dim text As String = match.Groups(j + 2).ToString()
            array(i, j) = text
            widths(j) = Math.Max(widths(j), text.Length)
        Next
    Next
    widths(3) = 0

    ' Align the four columns.
    DTE.UndoContext.Open("Align Properties")
    Try
        For i As Integer = 0 To endLine - startLine
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.GotoLine(startLine + i)
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.SelectLine()
            Dim line As String = DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.text()
            Dim replacement = leading
            For j As Integer = 0 To 3
                Dim padded As String = array(i, j).PadRight(widths(j) + 1)
                replacement = replacement & padded
            Next
            DTE.ActiveDocument.Selection.text() = replacement
        Next
    Finally
        DTE.UndoContext.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

Before:

[image: Before]

After:

[image: After]

Comment: Thanks for having a go at a VB macro. I should have been clearer perhaps that I was looking for a general solution that behaved along the lines of the algorithm I sketched out - not just a macro for auto--properties!

Answer (score 10):

Not quite a full solution, but [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/) has something similar called "Align Assignments":

> This extension is useful for making your code a little more readable by aligning the assignments when you type Ctrl+Alt+] such that it takes this:
>
> ```
> _test = test;
> _commandTarget = commandTarget;
> _state = state;
> ```
>
> And turns it into this:
>
> ```
> _test          = test;
> _commandTarget = commandTarget;
> _state         = state;
> ```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly the idea, but of course I want something general (not just for assignments).